# how do you integration OmniAuth (Twitter) to an existing user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, omniauth

I am using OmniAuth and I'm able to get the callback successfully working.

When I browse to `/auth/twitter` and log in using Twitter, it leads me back to `/auth/twitter/callback` with unformatted text that has user ID, profile image URL, screen name, etc.

I haven't done anything with this output yet and that's where I need help.

I already have an existing authentication system and I want to keep everything the way it is. I am looking to grab from Twitter just the screen name, their oauth_token, their oauth_token_secret and their email address (if possible) to create a new account on my site/login to my site. If I want to keep the exact same behavior of my current website and just want to allow people to login/register using Twitter, how can I do that?

Here's my already existing user table

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string    "name"
    t.string    "email"
    t.timestamp "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.timestamp "updated_at",                         :null => false
    t.string    "password_digest"
    t.string    "remember_token"
```

Can I add the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret columns to this table and make it work that way?

Comment: I'm using OmniAuth, not OAuth

Answer (score 0):

You can. Check Ryans railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth.  Also be aware that twitter does not return email. You may also need to change user model to allow null for password etc, if you are planning to allow login either with twitter or with traditional user/pass (you may need to work on validation part if the user chose the later)